# Geoserver Tile Generating

Tags: geoserver, tiles

I'm a complete newbie at this so please excuse my lack of knowledge. I need to be able to place hundreds of thousands of points on a map. I'm using OpenLayers with Google Maps base layer and I just installed OpenGeo Suite. I also need to be able to add/delete points and manipulate them real-time. Placing those points as a vector or marker layer doesn't work so I think I need to have the server generate tiles? Where do I start with this? I've scoured the documentation and this website and can't find where to begin with generating tiles and doing it dynamically with my data. Thanks!

Comment: You don't want tiles if your data is changing, look at WMS instead.

Comment: Great! Thanks! How do I get my data in the server? I have found information about how to get it back out but I'm confused on how to get the initial data in there. Should I use PostGIS?

Comment: did you look at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/gettingstarted/index.html? basically just import whatever you currently store your data in as a store/layer